# Table for the general solution of the system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

On this wikipedia page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/General_%3D_Particular_%2B_Homogeneous#th:GenEqPartPlusHomo, after the proof of corollary 3.11 there is a table that says this: no particular solution + infinite solutions to the homogenous system = no solutions. How can this be the case when if we are given a homogenous system at the start, an derive infinite number of solutions, there won't be a particular solution, and we can conclude that the solution set is infinite. Why does this say that there are no solutions? Can someone explain the table in general? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I have understood your post, but you seem to be considering the case where the homogeneous system has no particular solution.

This case is impossible since a homogeneous system means a system
$$A{\bf x}={\bf0}\ ,$$
and it always has a solution, for example, ${\bf x}={\bf0}$.

Comment: BTW have you solved **lots** of specific examples of linear systems?  If you haven't, I doubt that reading general results like that page will help much.

Comment: I thought that the zero vector as a solution to a homogenous system is not considered a particular solution. This is false right?

Comment: The word "particular" actually is pretty redundant.  A "particular solution" just means "a solution".  If it means anything, it is emphasizing that we are talking about **a (possible) solution** and not **the (complete) solution**.  Specifically, the zero vector is a (particular) solution of a homogeneous system.

Comment: Thanks. And how you find that a system has no particular solution? You see that it contains a contradiction and stop there or what? For to follow the table, you need to ensure that there is not a particular solution.

Comment: Yes, find a contradiction.  But as I said above, I think you are worrying too much about this table.  The first thing to do is solve specific examples, say 10 or 20 of them, both homogeneous and not.  Once you do this I think you will find that most of the ideas become pretty clear (and you won't need to memorise the table because you will find that it's obvious).

Answer (score 1):

For any solution $\mathbf v$ of $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$, $\mathbf v+\mathbf w$, where $\mathbf w$ is any solution of the homogeneous equation $A\mathbf x=0$, is also a solution. The vector $\mathbf v$ is called a *particular* solution of the equation. In fact, *all* solutions of the original equation are of this form. That’s the gist of the Wikipedia article that you reference in your question. The set of solution to the homogeneous equation is called the *null space* of $A$.

If there’s a nonzero solution to the homogeneous equation, the dimension of the null space is greater than zero and the original equation potentially has a multitude of solutions. However, unless $\mathbf b=0$, elements of the null space do not solve the original equation, so you need still some other vector that’s outside of the null space as a starting point for its solution set. (Indeed, for the equation to have any solution at all, $\mathbf b$ must be an element of $A$’s *column space*.) So it’s entirely possible for the homogenous equation to have an infinite number of solutions, but for the inhomogeneous equation to have none.